# How to define column specification for similarly named column with readr?

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I have a data base with 250 columns and want to read only 50 of them instead of loading all of them then dropping columns with `dplyr::select`. I suppose I can do that using a column specification. I don't want to type the column specification manually for all those columns.

The 50 columns I want to keep have a common prefix, say 'blop', so I managed to manually change the column specification object I got from `readr::spec_csv`. I then used it to read my data file :

```
short_colspec <- readr::spec_csv('myfile.csv')
short_colspec$cols <- lapply(names(short_colspec$cols), function(name){
    if (substr(name, 1, 4) == 'blop'){
        return(col_character())
    } else {
        return(col_skip())
    }
})
short_data <- read_csv('myfile.csv', col_types = short_colspec)
```

Is there a way to specify such a column specification with `readr` (or any other package) functions in a more robust way than what I did ?

Comment: Using `readr` it looks like how you've done it is the approach to take. It could potentially be improved with `grepl` as opposed to `substr` so as to be more flexible. Also your code assumes the columns you are reading in are all `col_character`

Comment: Indeed `grepl` provides more flexibility ! I assumed only string variables for the sake of simplicity, it is true that the `if else` syntax can be expanded to take into account more column types.

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table`'s `fread` you can select columns you want to skip (=drop) or keep (=select)

```
#read first line of file to select which columns to keep
#adjust the strsplit-character here ';' according to your csv-type
keep_col <- readLines( "myfile.csv", n = 1L ) %>% strsplit( ";" ) %>% el() %>% grep( "blop", . )
#read file, only the desired columns
fread( "myfile.csv", select = keep_col )
```